# MarginBottom doesn't apply with the Fabbutton when opening a modal in Ionic 6 / Capacitor

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a another problem after implementing this solution in my android app.

[How to use different admob methods in Ionic 6/Capacitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268878/how-to-use-different-admob-methods-in-ionic-6-capacitor)

The solutions works when I switch from page to page, but not when I open a modal. I have a component called fabbuton and this is the code.

**Fabbutton.html**

```
<div class="fixed">
  <ion-fab (click)="scrollToTop()" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button class="toolbar-color" size="small">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</div>
```

**Fabbutton.css**

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 0;
}
```

**Fabutton.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fabbutton',
  templateUrl: './fabbutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fabbutton.component.scss'],
})
export class FabbuttonComponent {
  
  @Output('onClick') onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

  scrollToTop() {
   this.onClick.emit();
  }
}
```

This is my admob service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AdMob, BannerAdOptions, BannerAdSize, BannerAdPosition, BannerAdPluginEvents } from '@capacitor-community/admob';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdMobService {

    private appMargin: number = 0;

    constructor(private platform: Platform) {
        this.init();
    }

    async init() {

        await this.platform.ready();
        await AdMob.initialize({
            requestTrackingAuthorization: true,
            initializeForTesting: true,
        }).catch(err => console.error('Could not init Admob', err));

        AdMob.addListener(BannerAdPluginEvents.SizeChanged, (info: any) => {
            // Subscribe Change Banner Size
            this.appMargin = parseInt(info.height, 10);
            if (this.appMargin > 0) {
                const app: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('ion-router-outlet');
                app.style.marginBottom = this.appMargin + 'px';
            }
        });
    }

    async bannerAd(admobId: string) {
        const options: BannerAdOptions = {
            adId: admobId,
            adSize: BannerAdSize.FULL_BANNER,
            position: BannerAdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            margin: 0,
            isTesting: true,
            npa: true
        };

        await AdMob.showBanner(options).catch(err => console.error('Could not init Admob banner', err));
    }
}
```

So when a add appears the fabbuton goes a little up like this:

[image]

When I open a **Modal** the fabbutton component goes behind the add like this:

[image]

In every page it works well, but only in the modal pages it doesn't add the margin bottom.

I have tried to overrule the CSS with the !important tag but still no luck.

How can I have the marginbottom in the modal like the other pages?

Comment: Sry, long time bootstrap user here, when you say modal you don't mean a dialog-box? Fixed position shouldn't change relative to the ad unless you change the fixed position with script or css. You can change the fixed postion relative to the ad or you can have the button being part of the ad element (or en element holding both) and set an absolute position ex top: -30px, that way it will always be above the ad.

Comment: Hello @Patrick, thanks for your time. What do you mean with part of the ad? Because I use typescript to show the ad and HTML for the fab button. Do you have a example?

Comment: Well give a chance to z-index. Try to give a huge value to fab something like 999 to goes to front of screen or if stills behind check modal z-index value and give to fab a higher value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution! This is a working example for me:

**Fabbutton.html**

```
<div class="fixed" [style]="'bottom:' + bottom + 'px'">
  <ion-fab (click)="scrollToTop()" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button class="toolbar-color" size="small">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</div>
```

**Fabbutton.ts**

```
@Input('bottom') public bottom = 30;
```

And call the selector like this:

```
<app-fabbutton bottom="100" (onClick)="scrollToTop()"></app-fabbutton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the css property --margin-bottom instead.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your time. When I use margin-bottom the fabbutton disappears..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a container around the AD and the button that would be fixed positioned at the bottom. The button would be absolute positioned relative to it's container and would change position depending on if it grows with the AD.

Here is a very basic example:

```js
function toggleAD() {
  var ad = document.getElementById("ad-bottom");
  if (ad.style.display === "none") {
    ad.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ad.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#ad-fab-container{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#ad-bottom{
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#fab-button{
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ad-fab-container">
  <button id="fab-button" onclick="toggleAD()">^</button>
  <div id="ad-bottom">This is an ad</div>
</div>
```